# how to get the count number by condition in r?

Tags: r

```
summary(as.factor(qanswer$q41))
 1    B    C    D    E  NA's 
112   66  127   45   30  896
```

I just want to get the number of 1,which is 112.then i tried:

```
length(qanswer$q41[qanswer$q41==1])
[1] 1008
> length(qanswer$q41[qanswer$q41=='1'])
[1] 1008
> length(qanswer$q41[qanswer$q41=='A'])
[1] 896
> length(qanswer$q41[qanswer$q41=='B'])
[1] 962
```

I made a function:

```
  x<-function(column){sum(column=='1',na.rm = TRUE)/sum(column,na.rm = TRUE)}
> x(qanswer$q41)
Error in sum(column, na.rm = TRUE) : 
invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

what's the problem?

Comment: You just need `sum(qanswer$q41==1, na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @akrun.I made a function:     
     > x<-function(column){sum(column=='1',na.rm = TRUE)/sum(column,na.rm = TRUE)}
    > x(qanswer$q41)
    Error in sum(column, na.rm = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: It is getting the error because your denominatior is `sum(column, ...` which is a character column with `'A', 'B', etc. string.   I guess you want something else.

Comment: Perhaps you need `/length(column)` or `/sum(!is.na(column))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sum`

```
sum(qanswer$q41==1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

As there are NA values in the 'q41' column, the `==` returns NA for those NA elements and by subsetting `qanswer$q41[qanswer$q41==1]`, the length will also include the 896 NAs, i.e.

```
896+ 112 = 1008
```

Instead, we need to make sure that the NAs are either removed (`na.rm=TRUE`) in the `sum` or use `!is.na` if we wanted to try with `length`

```
length(qanswer$41[qanswer$q41==1 & !is.na(qanswer$q41)])
```